# Istio - Kiali - upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-ingress, istio, kiali

Hi I am working on Istio and following this [link/doc](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/gateways/#option-2-insecure-access-http) to remotely access `Kiali dashboard`. 
Using the `YAML's` I am able to access `Grafana, Prometheus and Tracing` using `CLusterIP:nodePort`.

But the Kiali endpoint gives error,

```
upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers
```

Command `kubectl get svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system` shows below ports,

```
80:31380/TCP,443:31390/TCP,31400:31400/TCP,15011:30716/TCP,8060:32087/TCP,853:30887/TCP,15030:31311/TCP,15031:31312/TCP,15032:31313/TCP,15029:31314/TCP
```

I can access Grafana at `http://33.33.333.33:31312`, Prometheus at `http://33.33.333.33:31311`, Tracing at `http://33.33.333.33:31313`

Kiali is mapped to `15029:31314/TCP` and is not accessible on `http://33.33.333.33:31314`

I am using Openshift v3.9,

> ```
> oc v3.9.0+191fece
> kubernetes v1.9.1+a0ce1bc657
> Istio -
> Version: 1.0.5
> GitRevision: c1707e45e71c75d74bf3a5dec8c7086f32f32fad
> GolangVersion: go1.10.4
> ```

Note - I understand I am running v1.0.5 and referring to v1.4.0 documentation. But I made the required port changes in the `istio-ingressgateway service yaml` by which tracing is working but kiali isn't,

```
ports:
    - name: http2
      nodePort: 31380
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
    - name: https
      nodePort: 31390
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 443
    - name: tcp
      nodePort: 31400
      port: 31400
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 31400
    - name: tcp-pilot-grpc-tls
      nodePort: 30716
      port: 15011
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 15011
    - name: tcp-citadel-grpc-tls
      nodePort: 32087
      port: 8060
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8060
    - name: tcp-dns-tls
      nodePort: 30887
      port: 853
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 853
    - name: http2-prometheus
      nodePort: 31311
      port: 15030
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 15030
    - name: http2-grafana
      nodePort: 31312
      port: 15031
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 15031
    - name: http2-tracing
      nodePort: 31313
      port: 15032
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 15032
    - name: http2-kiali
      nodePort: 31314
      port: 15029
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 15029
```

Comment: You mean you are accessing grafana through istio-ingressgateway pod?

Comment: Yes, I am accessing the telemetry add-ons outside of a cluster using an ingress gateway.

Comment: Hi, can You add istio version, kubernetes version and cluster infrastructure?

Comment: Updated my post with the details.